# Can Visual Studio 2019 be configured to treat old style and new SDK style projects the same in the Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio

When you double click or press Enter on an old style project, it expands or collapses. On the new "SDK" style ones, it opens the project file itself. The inconsistency is inconvenient and distracting. I would prefer that the original behavior applied to both types. None of this appears to be a property configurable keyboard shortcut. It is notable that Project.EditProjectFile is available, but not helpful in making this consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to BooDeeHoo on reddit, I got an answer:

> The setting you are looking for is Tools>Options>Projects and
> Solutions >Open project files with double-click or the Enter key when
> supported.
>
> Uncheck it to get the legacy behavior on .Net core projects.

[Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/jpc1au/inconsistent_solution_explorer_behavior_based_on/)